# Changing all data in mysql database

Tags: mysql, field, record

What would be the sql statement to change the value of order_status field to 3 of all order_id that are between 1 and 700.

Mysql Database name is test_test

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

```
update tablename
set order_status = 3
where order_id between 1 and 700
```

It's almost the same as the words in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
USE test_test;
UPDATE `order` SET order_status = 3 WHERE order_id BETWEEN 1 AND 700
```